# Prove that any complete graph $K_n$ is antimagic for $n$>=3.

Tags: graph-theory

I guess that the proof is related to the decomposition of complete graph into Hamilton cycles, but I do not know how to approach it.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: I think induction works, thanks.